# Python list printing character of element instead of whole element

Tags: python, string, list, printing

I have a dataframe column which consists of lists (each row contain elements in a list). When I tried to print each row with for loop its fine. but when I tried to print each element within each row it gives me each element instead of a actual element in a list.

I used csv reader to import data set so my column was string. I have tried converting str to list but still could not able to solve this problem

```
    column_A
--------------------
['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl']
['mno']
['pqr', 'st', 'uv']
['wx', 'yz']

for x in df['column_A']:
    print(x)

#this is fine

for x in df['column_A']:
    for xs in x:
       print(xs)
```

It gives this output :

```
 [
 b
 c
 ,
 d     ....
```

expected result :

```
 abc
 def
 ghi
 jkl     ....
```

Comment: No logical error in your method, plz examine what you have provided carefully

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension to flatten the nested list that exists as a column in your dataframe.

```
nested_list = list(df['column_A'])

[item for sublist in nested_list for item in sublist]
```

```
['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'mno', 'pqr', 'st', 'uv', 'wx', 'yz']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ast.literal_eval` to convert the sting to a list object.

**Ex:**

```
import ast
df = pd.DataFrame({'column_A': ["[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]", "[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]"]})

for x in df['column_A'].apply(ast.literal_eval):
    for xs in x:
        print(xs)
```